# Python Classes and Object assignment

Tags: python

I need to write a program that does the following:
First, find the County that has the highest turnout, i.e. the highest percentage of the
population who voted, using the objects’ population and voters attributes
Then, return a tuple containing the name of the County with the highest turnout and the
percentage of the population who voted, in that order; the percentage should be
represented as a number between 0 and 1.

I took a crack at it, but am getting the following error:

Error on line 19:
allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Here is what I've done so far. Thank you so much for your help.

```
class County:
  def __innit__(self, innit_name, innit_population, innit_voters) :
   self.name = innit_name
   self.population = innit_population
   self.voters = innit_voters
    
def highest_turnout(data) :
  highest_turnout = data[0]
  for County in data:
    if (county.voters / county.population) > (highest_turnout.voters / highest_turnout.population):
      highest_turnout = county

  return highest_turnout

# your program will be evaluated using these objects 
# it is okay to change/remove these lines but your program
# will be evaluated using these as inputs
allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)
data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]  

result = highest_turnout(data) # do not change this line!
print(result) # prints the output of the function
# do not remove this line!
```

Comment: You have a spelling mistake, the init method should be named `__init__ ` not `__innit__ `

Answer (score 1):

`def __innit__(self, innit_name, innit_population, innit_voters) :`
You mispelled `__init__`